# Laurent series of $f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{\sin(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

How does one find the first four terms of the Laurent series of $f(z) = \frac{z^2+1}{\sin(z)}$? My approach was this:

$(z^2+1) = f(z)\sin(z) = \left(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n \right)\sin(z)=\left(\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n z^n \right)\left(z-\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^5}{120}-\frac{z^7}{5040} \right)$.

How do we proceed further?

Comment: Expand the right hand side and identify coefficients. (It may be easier if you determine the order the pole first, so you can drop most $c_n$ with negative index.)

Comment: How can the order of the pole be determined in this case?

Comment: Laurent series...around *what point*? And do you want the whole development or a few terms are enough, say to find out what the residue is in that point (perhaps zero...)?

Comment: Around $z=0$ I think, but it's not specified.  One can see that if $z=k\pi$, then there are infinitely many $k$'s. Does this mean that this is an essential singularity, since there are infinitely many singular points there?

Comment: @sequence No, the singular points still are isolated and, in fact, they all are simple ploes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, very close to zero we have

$$\frac{z^2+1}{\sin z}=\frac{z^2+1}{z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\ldots}=\frac{z^2+1}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{120}-\ldots\right)}\stackrel{\text{Devel. of geom. series}}=$$

$$=\left(z+\frac1z\right)\left(1+\frac{z^2}6+\frac{z^4}{36}+\ldots\right)=\frac1z+\frac76z+\frac7{36}z^3+\ldots$$

With the above you already have the pole at $\;z=0\;$ is a simple one and its residue is $\;1\;$ .

Comment: The expansion of  $\sin z$  is wrong.

Comment: $\sin(z) =z-\frac16z^3+\frac{1}{120}z^5+O(z^7)$

Comment: Right, I didn't have to rearrange the terms in the first place, to make things more confusing.

Comment: Yop. Thank you all, I drifted towards the cosine development for some reason. Edited.

Comment: @DonAntonio can  you please explain how you transformed the term $\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{z^2}{3!}-\frac{z^4}{5!}+\frac{z^6}{7!}\right)}$? I'm not sure how to apply geometric series to something like this.

Comment: @sequence The idea here is that we're only interested in a very small neighborhood of $\;z=0\;$ (say, because we want to know what kind of singularity it is, what its residue, etc.), so we can take only $\;1-\frac{z^2}6\;$ and all the rest "to throw them away", meaning they will be negligible in such a small neighborhood, and of course $\;\left|\frac{x^2}6\right|<1\;$ here, so we can use the development of a geometric series $$\frac1{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\ldots\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;|z|<1\;$$ , and that's what I did above.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{z^2+1}{\sin z}=\biggl( z+\frac 1z\biggr)\frac z{\sin z},$$
so all you have to find is the expansion of
$$\frac z{\sin z}=\frac 1{1-\cfrac{z^2}6+\cfrac{z^4}{120}+\cfrac{z^6}{5040}+o(z^7)}$$

It can be obtained with a division by *increasing powers* of $x$:
$$\begin{array}{rrrrr}
&&1&{}+\dfrac{z^2}6&{}+\dfrac{7z^4}{360}&{}+\dfrac{31z^6}{15120}\\
1-\dfrac{z^2}6+\dfrac{z^4}{120}-\dfrac{z^6}{5040}&\Big(&1\\%
&&-1&{}+\dfrac{z^2}6&{}-\dfrac{z^4}{120}&{}+\dfrac{z^6}{5040}\\
\hline 
&&&\dfrac{z^2}6&{}-\dfrac{z^4}{120}&{}+\dfrac{z^6}{5040}\\
&&&-\dfrac{z^2}6&{}+\dfrac{z^4}{36}&{}-\dfrac{z^6}{360}\\
\hline 
%&&&&{}+\dfrac{7z^4}{360}&{}-\dfrac{z^6}{840}\\
%&&&&{}-\dfrac{7z^4}{360}&{}\dfrac{7z^6}{2160}\\
%\hline
&&&&&\dfrac{31z^6}{15120}\end{array}$$ 
whence the *Laurent series* after multiplication by $z+\dfrac1z$:

\begin{alignat*}{6}
\frac{z^2+1}{\sin z}=\biggl(z+\frac 1z\biggr)\frac z{\sin z}&=&&z+\dfrac{z^3}6&&+\dfrac{7z^5}{360}+\dfrac{31z^7}{15120}+o(z^8)
\\
&=\quad \frac1z+&&\dfrac{z}6+\dfrac{7z^3}{360}&&+\dfrac{31z^5}{15120}+o(z^6)\\
& =
\quad \color{red}{\frac1z+}&&\color{red}{\dfrac{7z}6+\dfrac{67z^3}{360}}&&\color{red}{{}+\dfrac{65z^5}{3024}+o(z^6)}.\end{alignat*}

*Added:  Division by increasing power order*

It's like *Euclidean division of polynomials* $A(x)$ (dividend) and $B(x)$ (divisor), except it is defined when $B(0)\neq 0$, i.e. the divisor has a non-zero constant term, and at each step, one divides the lowest term of the dividend by the constant term of the divisor in order to eliminate the lowest term of the dividend.

The  result we use is the following:

> Let $A(x)$, $B(x)$ be polynomials. For each natural number $n$, there exists a unique pair of polynomials $Q_n(x)$ and $R_n(x)$ such that
>   $$A(x)=Q_n(x)B(x)+x^{n+1}R_n(x),\qquad\deg Q_n(x)\le n.$$

From unicity, we see that, for $m\le n$, $Q_m(x)$ is just the polynomial $Q_n(x)$, truncated at degree $m$.

This division can be used for the expansion in power series of the quotient $f(x)/g(x)$ of two analytic functions, and to find quickly the decomposition into partial fractions in the case of multiple poles.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how your division process works. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @sequence: I've added some explanations. Hope it's clearer. You also can take a look at [this page](https://mathematicalgarden.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/division-by-increasing-power-order/).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but without determining the order of the pole $z=0$ you are stuck because each coefficient of $f \cdot \sin$ will, in principle, be a sum with infinitely many terms. Finding the order of the pole of $f$ will allow us to kill infinitely many of these, leaving only finitely many of them, as you are going to see.

Remember that the Taylor series of $\sin$ around $z=0$ begins with $z^1$, so $0$ is a zero of order $1$ for $\sin$, therefore it is a pole of order $1$ for $\frac 1 \sin$.

For even greater clarity, remember that $z_0$ is a pole of order $n>0$ for $f$ if and only if $n$ is *smallest* with the property $\lim \limits _{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^n f(z) \ne 0$. Let's check this for your $f$ and $n=1$:

$$\lim _{z \to 0} z \ \frac {z^2 + 1} {\sin z} = \lim _{z \to 0} \frac z {\sin z} (z^2 + 1) = \lim _{z \to 0} \frac z {\sin z} \lim _{z \to 0} (z^2 + 1) = 1 \cdot 1 = 1 .$$

Is $n=1$ the smallest such *strictly* positive number? Yes, because below it there is only $0$, and $0$ is not allowed to be the order of a pole, by definition.

Having found the order of the pole of $f$ is essential, since this allows us to restrict the lower bound for the summation index:

$$f(z) = \sum _{n = -1} ^\infty c_n z^n$$

(notice that $n$ starts now at $-1$, not at $-\infty$).

Plugging this into your own approach (and keeping only terms up to and including $z^3$, because you want only the first 4 terms) gives

$$z^2 + 1 = \left( \sum _{n =-1} ^\infty c_n z^n \right) \left( z - \frac {z^3} {3!} + \frac {z^5} {5!} - \frac {z^7} {7!} + \dots \right) = \\
\left( c_{-1} - \frac {c_{-1}} {3!} z^2 + \dots \right) + \left( c_0 z - \frac {c_0} {3!} z^3 + \dots \right) + \left( c_1 z^2 + \dots \right) + \left( c_2 z^3 + \dots \right) + \dots ,$$

so equating the coefficients of the corresponding powers of $z$ in both hands of the equation gives

$$c_{-1} = 1, \quad c_0 = 0, \quad -\frac {c_{-1}} 6 + c_1 = 1, \quad -\frac {c_0} 6 + c_2 = 0 ,$$

whence it follows that

$$c_{-1} = 1, \quad c_0 = 0, \quad c_1 = \frac 7 6, \quad c_2 = 0 ,$$

so

$$f(z) = \frac 1 z + \frac 7 6 z + \dots .$$

Notice that there is no surprise in the fact that $c_0 = c_2 = 0$, because

$$f(-z) = \frac {(-z)^2 + 1} {\sin (-z)} = \frac {z^2 + 1} {-\sin z} = -f(z) ,$$

so $f$ is odd, and the coefficients of *even* order of an *odd* function are always $0$.